# Customize ggcorrplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggcorrplot

I am working with a connectivity matrix of a network with positive values only and I want to display it before and after a threshold being applied. I´ve already used `corrplot` library, which allows plenty of changes in legend and colors but I decided to use `ggcorrplot` because `corrplot` figures get changed when I try to put them together in a graph trough `grid.arrange`. The main problem with `ggcorrplot` is that I haven´t been able to change legend values to be only between 0 and 1. My code is the next

```
    library(ggcorrplot)
    library(ggplot)

    ggcorrplot(prom_orig_sub, legend.title = "Coherencia")
```

[image]

Could you suggest some solution to change legend values? Thak you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overwriting the fill with `scale_fill_gradient`. It would likely alter the default colour scheme for `ggcorrplot` though.

```
ggcorrplot(prom_orig_sub, legend.title = "Coherencia") + 
     scale_fill_gradient2(breaks=c(0, 1), limit=c(0, 1))
```

Comment: To maintain the "white through red" gradient that is the default for ggcorrplot: `scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red", breaks=c(0, 1), limit=c(0, 1))`

Comment: Note also that adding `scale_fill_gradient2` breaks `legend.title`.  This can be solved by passing the desired legend title in `labs` like so: `ggcorrplot(prom_orig_sub) + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red", breaks=c(0, 1), limit=c(0, 1)) + labs(fill = "Coherencia")`